# Can't create Symfony 4 projects

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony4

i'm working already with symfony 3, I've create a lot of project with it, so now i'm trying to create a project with symfony 4, but i can't when i type this command :

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton my-project-symf-4
```

the project is created successfully, but the problem that is created with this version 3.4 instead of 4.2,

```
Installing symfony/skeleton (v3.4.22.1)
  - Installing symfony/skeleton (v3.4.22.1): Downloading (100%)
Created project in my-project-symf-4
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Package operations: 22 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing symfony/flex (v1.1.8): Downloading (100%)

Prefetching 21 packages
  - Downloading (100%)
  - Installing psr/cache (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/container (1.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/simple-cache (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.10.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/log (1.1.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/debug (v3.4.22): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/console (v3.4.22): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/dotenv (v3.4.22): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/routing (v3.4.22): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v3.4.22): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v3.4.22): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/http-kernel (v3.4.22): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/finder (v3.4.22): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/filesystem (v3.4.22): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/dependency-injection (v3.4.22): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/config (v3.4.22): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/class-loader (v3.4.22): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-apcu (v1.10.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/cache (v3.4.22): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/framework-bundle (v3.4.22): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/yaml (v3.4.22): Loading from cache
Generating autoload files
```

So as you can see the composer load all packages from cache.
I've try to clear composer cache like this:

```
$ composer clearcache
```

but without result, the problem still exist.

My PHP Version is 7.3.1

Can anyone help me to resolve that problem?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: does `php -v` report that you use 7.3.1 on the shell? Probably your shell version of PHP is still v7.0.x, as later versions of the skeleton require at least PHP 7.1

Comment: Do you have a global composer config where you specify custom package repositories like a Satis or private packagist? If so, are you sure they have the up to date `symfony/skeleton` available?

Comment: How do i know if i have global composer config ?

Comment: thanks @NicoHaase you are right i have to update the php version on shell to 7.2 and it's work like charm

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the symfony version (4.2 for example) like that:

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton:4.2 my-project-symf-4
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: it give me that error :
[InvalidArgumentException]
Could not find package symfony/skeleton with version 4.2.

Comment: Even if the [correct composer command](https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/setup.html#creating-symfony-applications-with-composer) was used, this would still fail since the php command line version is less than 7.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed symfony CLI in your system then you just run the below command with specifying version number

For Example to create a Symfony project with 4.4 version run following command

symfony new my_project_name --version=4.4